# Просмотр базы данных с конца

Tags: python, django

Представим есть код:

```
for i in new['test']:
     if str(new1[1]['id']) != i.news_id:
                 hy = new1[1]['text']
```

`i.news_id` -  строка из базы данных. Но просматривать значения в бд нужно с конца, как это можно сделать?

Comment: База сама умеет сортировать записи. Не знаю, как вы работаете с базой, но в SQL для этого используется `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Или `ORDER BY DESC`